# Reverse all strings of several files

Tags: c, string, pointers, reverse

I need a program to reverse the order of all strings stored in one or more text files. This is what i've got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i < argc;i++)
    {
        FILE *MyFile=fopen(argv[i], "r");
        int i,len;
        char str[1000], *ptr;
        fgets(str, 1000, MyFile);
        ptr = str;
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            if(*ptr == '\0')  break;
            ptr++;
        }
        len = i;
        ptr--;
        for(i=len; i>0; i--)
        {
            printf("%c",*ptr--);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose (MyFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What i'm not being able to do is to loop the program correctly so that it reverses all strings. Currently it reverses the first string of all files, but when it encounters a line break the fgets stops. What i've tried to do is to count the lines in the current file, do a for loop, and at the end do another `fgets(str, 1000, MyFile);` to advance the fgets, but I somehow manage to mess things up.

Another option I thought of is to create a separate function which only reverses a given string, and inside the main function call that function the appropriate number of times, but i'm not sure how to handle the argc and *argv[] in this situation.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: The second option is close to what you should do (break the problem/program in smaller sections), but I do not understand the "I´m not sure how to handle argc and * argv[]" issue. Such a function probably does not need to know anything about `argc` or `argv`, which is the issue that you have?

Comment: Are you trying to produce output with each line of the file reversed, or with the order of lines within the files reversed?

Comment: Contents reversed, s a file with:
ABCD
1234
Should output:
DCBA
4321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are clobbering the `i` variable for the outer loop with another one declared inside. This is most probably why it doesn't work.
- You should use `strlen()` function to get the string length instead of calculating it manually.
- Unless you are *guaranteed* to have strings of at most 1000 bytes, you should consider using a smarter algorithm to cater for longer strings.

Comment: OP has two variables `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate each `char` in a buffer until end-of-string (`\0`) detected.  Then print it in reverse.

```
printf_reverse(const char *buf, size_t len) {
  while (len > 0) {
    fputc(buf[--len], stdout);
  }
}

char buf[1000];
size_t len = 0;
int ch;
while ((ch == fgetc(MyFile)) != EOF) {
  if (ch == '\0') {
    printf_reverse(buf, len);
    len = 0;
  }
  // You may want not use EOL as part of the reverse
  else if (ch == '\n') {
    printf_reverse(buf, len);
    fputc(ch, stdout);
    len = 0;
  }
  else if (len < sizeof(buf)) {
    buf[len++] = ch;
  }
  else {
    ; // handle error string too long
  }
printf_reverse(buf, len);
```

OP says "ABCD 1234 Should output: DCBA 4321".   In C, a string ends with a `\0`.  It is not clear if the source file has embedded `\0` or OP also wants to use a space to indicate the end of the string.